# How to rectify this error? When I used multirow tag its overlaps the next cell

Tags: tables, errors

```
\begin{tabular}{ p{2.2cm}p{2.2cm}p{2.2cm}p{7cm} }

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Approach} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Technique Used} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Premise considered} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Attributes} \\ \hline

\multirow{2}{*}{Virtual forces} & Potential Fields [16] & Location information and range & Balanced deployment with the help of repulsive mechanism, when in proximity to obstacles. \\ \cline{2-4}
 & DSS Algorithm [17]   & Location information & A profitable scheme to conserve energy during deployment of a WSN divided into clusters. \\
 \hline

\multirow{2}{*}{Computational Geometry} & Co-Fi [18] & Location information & Distributed scheme to conserve energy and provide regulated coverage fidelity. \\ \cline{2-4}
 & VEC, VOR, Minmax [19] & Location information & Identify coverage holes and enabling sensors to move away from dense area. \\ 
 \hline

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Please make your code a complete document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` by adding a documentclass and the packages you need.

Comment: It's impossible for `Computational Geometry` to fit in 2.2cm.

Answer (score 1):

No time for explanations right now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{showframe}   %%% just for demo Remove
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}}%
                    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.4\textwidth-8\tabcolsep\relax} }
\hline
\bfseries Approach & \bfseries Technique Used & \bfseries Premise considered & \bfseries Attributes \\ \hline

\multirow{2}{*}[-6em]{Virtual forces} & Potential Fields [16] & Location information and range & Balanced deployment with the help of repulsive mechanism, when in proximity to obstacles. \\ \cline{2-4}
 & DSS Algorithm [17]   & Location information & A profitable scheme to conserve energy during deployment of a WSN divided into clusters. \\
 \hline

\multirow{2}{0.2\textwidth}[-4.5em]{Computational Geometry} & Co-Fi [18] & Location information & Distributed scheme to conserve energy and provide regulated coverage fidelity. \\ \cline{2-4}
 & VEC, VOR, Minmax [19] & Location information & Identify coverage holes and enabling sensors to move away from dense area. \\
 \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]